# Is it possible to store Unity models in a persistent data path?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm relatively new to Unity and any help would be greatly appreciated. I need to import Unity models (comprised of .fbx/.obj files, associated materials (.mat) and textures (.bmp) and store them into a persistent data path (application.persistentdatapath), **is this possible?**

From the examples I've witnessed on various sites (including YouTube), most cases store game related data (e.g. health, levels, player/game info etc.) in a persistent data path, and not any model(s) per se...

I'll need to store the model(s) locally to the device and not the Unity game folder itself, so this may rule out using Application.streamingAssetsPath...:(, **unless anyone can shed more light?**

Thanks,

Comment: Why, can‘t the model files be inside the unity game folder? If you want to load them from a web server instead of shipping it with your game, that a look at asset bundles and addressables, but the models will still be in the unity assets folder.

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundles-Workflow.html

Comment: `is this possible?` Yes sure! The question is how exactly do you need you data? `FBX` or `OBJ` are both open file formats you can read/write and for both there already exist Unity packages like [Scene OBJ Expoerter](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/scene-obj-exporter-22250) or [ExportOBJ](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/ExportOBJ) and e.g. [UnityFBXExporter](https://github.com/KellanHiggins/UnityFBXExporter)